# Error in identifying url by clicking on it

Tags: android, webview, onload, onload-event, webviewclient

I have 3 pages, my webview takes me to page 1, in page 1 you can go to page 2 or 3, I'm trying to identify if you go to page 2 or 3 from page 1. I'm trying to perform an action type, Toast or Intent in my WebView by clicking on a link, but in method to make the Toast onLoadResource send me the error "The method Maketext (Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Class , String, int)"
I can do about it to fix this?

```
public class WebViewTest extends Activity{
WebView site;
String webUrl;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.coursetest);

    site = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvcurse);
    site.loadUrl("http://wstest.comuf.com/test/webviewtest.html");

    site.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    site.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    site.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    site.setWebViewClient(new ViewClient());}}
```

my ViewClient.java class is;

```
    public class ViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url){
    super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(v, url);
    v.loadUrl(url); 

    return true;    
}
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  v, String  url){
        super.onLoadResource(v, url);
        if( url.equals("http://www.wstest.comuf.com/test/page_two.html") ){

            Toast t=Toast.makeText(WebViewTest.class,"passed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();

           // Intent i = new Intent("com.mariposatraining.courses.lay_main");
          //startActivity(i); here too i have the error "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type ViewClient"
        }
        if( url.equals("http://www.wstest.comuf.com/test/page_three.html") ){

            Toast t=Toast.makeText(WebViewTest.class,"failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }                       
}}
```

How should I make toast or other activity work here?
Really would appreciate your help.

Comment: print your url in log and check result first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature of [`Toast.makeText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) that you're trying to use is:

> public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

`WebViewTest.class` is not a `Context`.

Comment: i'm trying to show this Toast on the layout of the class WebViewTest.class, so, how i should to put my line of context in the toast, to successfully perform the action?

Comment: Toasts appear on top of everything. You don't have to (nor can you) specify which layout for it to appear on top of. Simply pass it a valid context.